# Using Pingar API in Python. Server raises Webfault: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: python, api, wsdl

Good evening to everyone.
I wanna mention that I'm pretty new on this whole thing about wsdl,soap,suds! Gonna try to provide as much info as possible. The wsdl is this one http://api3.pingar.com/PingarAPIService.asmx?WSDL

I spent hours trying to find what's wrong with the code I'm using, but ended up to nothing. I borrowed the code found here: https://gist.github.com/maheshcr/1829570 , and filled up the necessary fields (AppID,KeyID).
My problem is that when I ran this code, i receive:
Server raised fault: 'Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

By the time I spent online looking on similar problems, I thought that it has to be a misprint. After double checking and comparing the wsdl with the code calls, I didn't find any mistakes at all.

I'm really out of ideas and as last resort I'm here asking for help.
Here is the body of the request printed on my command line:

```
(PingarAPIRequest){
   AppID = "12345abc" #hypothetical appid
   AppKey = "abcd123456" #hypothetical appkey
   Language = "en"
   RapidDiscovery = 
      (RapidDiscovery){
         Query = None
         Documents = 
            (Documents){
               string[] = <empty>
            }
         DocumentsFormat = <empty>
         NumberOfResults = None
         SummaryLength = None
         MinKeyphraseness = None
      }
   EntityExtraction = 
      (EntityExtractionRequest){
         Documents = 
            (ArrayOfString){
               string[] = 
                  "Just a random input where we expect to find iron man 3 and the hobbit as the extracted entities.
",
            }
         DocumentsFormat = "Text"
         IncludeSingleSiblings = True
         TaxonomyNames = 
            (TaxonomyNames){
               string[] = <empty>
            }
         NumberOfKeywords = 10
         EntitiesToExtract = 
            (EntitiesToExtract){
               EntityTypes[] = <empty>
            }
         WikifyLinkDensity = 0.5
      }
   ContentAnalysis = 
      (ContentAnalysis){
         Documents = 
            (Documents){
               string[] = <empty>
            }
         DocumentsFormat = <empty>
         SummaryLength = None
         EntitiesToRedact = 
            (EntitiesToRedact){
               EntityTypes[] = <empty>
            }
         EntitiesToSanitize = 
            (EntitiesToSanitize){
               EntityTypes[] = <empty>
            }
      }
 }
```

Any help and/or advice will be highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your time, and I'll make sure to post any more info asked asap. I hope this post, help others out too.

EDIT: I thought it would be useful to add the suds.logging information.
Debug mode - suds.client:

```
DEBUG:suds.client:sending to (http://api3.pingar.com/PingarAPIService.asmx)
message:
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://api.pingar.com/" xmlns:SOAP-             ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-    ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns0:GetEntities>
         <ns0:request>
            <ns0:AppID>hypothetical appID</ns0:AppID>
            <ns0:AppKey>hypothetical appKey</ns0:AppKey>
            <ns0:Language xsi:type="ns0:LanguageCodes">en</ns0:Language>
            <ns0:EntityExtraction>
               <ns0:Documents>
                  <ns0:string>Just a random input where we expect to find iron man 3     and the hobbit as the extracted entities.
</ns0:string>
               </ns0:Documents>
               <ns0:DocumentsFormat     xsi:type="ns0:DocumentFormat">Text</ns0:DocumentsFormat>
               <ns0:IncludeSingleSiblings>true</ns0:IncludeSingleSiblings>
               <ns0:NumberOfKeywords>50</ns0:NumberOfKeywords>
               <ns0:WikifyLinkDensity>0.5</ns0:WikifyLinkDensity>
            </ns0:EntityExtraction>
         </ns0:request>
      </ns0:GetEntities>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
DEBUG:suds.client:headers = {'SOAPAction': u'"http://api(dot)pingar.com/GetEntities"',     'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}
ERROR:suds.client:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://api(dot)pingar.com/" xmlns:SOAP-    ENC="http://schemas(dot)xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"     xmlns:xsi="http://www(dot)w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-    ENV="http://schemas(dot)xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns0:GetEntities>
         <ns0:request>
            <ns0:AppID>hypothetical appid</ns0:AppID>
            <ns0:AppKey>hypothetical appkey</ns0:AppKey>
            <ns0:Language xsi:type="ns0:LanguageCodes">en</ns0:Language>
            <ns0:EntityExtraction>
               <ns0:Documents>
                  <ns0:string>Just a random input where we expect to find iron man 3     and the hobbit as the extracted entities.
</ns0:string>
               </ns0:Documents>
               <ns0:DocumentsFormat     xsi:type="ns0:DocumentFormat">Text</ns0:DocumentsFormat>
               <ns0:IncludeSingleSiblings>true</ns0:IncludeSingleSiblings>
               <ns0:NumberOfKeywords>50</ns0:NumberOfKeywords>
               <ns0:WikifyLinkDensity>0.5</ns0:WikifyLinkDensity>
            </ns0:EntityExtraction>
         </ns0:request>
      </ns0:GetEntities>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
DEBUG:suds.client:http failed:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault>    <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Server was unable to process request. ---    &gt; Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</faultstring><detail />    </soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
Server raised fault: 'Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference     not set to an instance of an object.'
```

Comment: can't figure out anything from this request only. Paste your client code here. Object reference not set to an instance of an object means before calling this web service, the request object which you have created in your code is referring to null.

Comment: one more thing i noticed in your request above, like  RapidDiscovery, why did you include that in your request when you are providing nothing in those fields. Because under that within documents node all fields are mandatory, may be your server is throwing fault due to those empty values. You can remove all nodes which you are sending empty or none.

Comment: The client code is exact the same as found here: https://gist.github.com/maheshcr/1829570 (That is supposed to work). Now about the two useless nodes in the request -RapidDiscovery and ContentAnalysis-, I had the same thought and checked out why are these created, and the only thing I came up is that they are generate by default with the     apiRequest = client.factory.create("PingarAPIRequest")     call.

Answer (score 0):

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://api.pingar.com/" xmlns:SOAP-             ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-    ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

correct above line. Remove spaces in your request soap-ENV like in between SOAP- ENC and SOAP-ENV, you will get your response. I tried with soapui and i am getting response.

I tried with following request by removing spaces.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://api.pingar.com/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns0:GetEntities>
     <ns0:request>
        <ns0:AppID>hypothetical appID</ns0:AppID>
        <ns0:AppKey>hypothetical appKey</ns0:AppKey>
        <ns0:Language xsi:type="ns0:LanguageCodes">en</ns0:Language>
        <ns0:EntityExtraction>
           <ns0:Documents>
              <ns0:string>Just a random input where we expect to find iron man 3      and the hobbit as the extracted entities.
    </ns0:string>
           </ns0:Documents>
           <ns0:DocumentsFormat      xsi:type="ns0:DocumentFormat">Text</ns0:DocumentsFormat>
           <ns0:IncludeSingleSiblings>true</ns0:IncludeSingleSiblings>
           <ns0:NumberOfKeywords>50</ns0:NumberOfKeywords>
           <ns0:WikifyLinkDensity>0.5</ns0:WikifyLinkDensity>
        </ns0:EntityExtraction>
     </ns0:request>
    </ns0:GetEntities>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and thoughts, but as I'm new in these topics, how am I suppose to do that through the python code I got? Or is that I just can't do it through python and I need SoapUI? (Sorry for my late response, but i'm kinda busy working on other parts of my project.)

Comment: I don't know why it's injecting tabs or spaces in tag's property. I am not familiar with suds client or python. May be they fix it through patches or updates. No idea.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyways. I'll post here if I find any solution.